# Creating query in nested django model and group the results in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to create query in my postgresql database with django ORM and then group the results by specific ip_addr. Here is my models:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    network = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.network}_{str(self.timestamp)}"


class Device(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip_addr = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    mac_addr = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ip_addr


class Port(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    port = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    application = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.port)
```

When I perform query `Port.objects.filter(host__report_id=pk)` I get all the port in specific Report. My problem is that I do not know how to group all ports whit the ip_addr they belong to. I will appreciate any useful advice.

Comment: The IP address is specified by the `host` right?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can "ship" the `ip_addr`ess of the related `Device` with our query and perform the grouping at the Django level, for example with [**`itertools.groupby`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), like:

```
from django.db.models import F
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

qs = Port.objects.annotate(
    ip_addr=F('host__ip_addr')
).filter(
    host__report_id=pk
).order_by('ip_addr')

result = {
    k: list(vs)
    for k, vs in groupby(qs, attrgetter('ip_addr'))
}
```

Here `result` is a `dict`ionary that maps the IP addresses on a list of related `Port` objects.

Comment: What is vs variable in `k: list(vs)`?

Comment: @MihaelWaschl: sorry, the iterator is `k, vs`, so it is the second item in the tuples that `groupby(..)` emits.

Comment: Thanks, great solution.